# What's the difference between signing a file and decrypting a file?

Tags: certificate, rsa, public-key-encryption, sign

What the difference between generating a RSA digital signature VS RSA decryption ???

If I have a hash of a message how can I generate a digital signature of that message ???

Comment: Encryption, using the public key, makes the plain text unreadable, decryption, using the private key, makes it readable again. Signature, created by private key, proves authenticity by allowing to validate with the public key.

How can you create a signature? Could you provide some details about the environment your working in? For instance what programming language you are using?

Answer (score 0):

### Encryption Decryption Vs Digital Signature

1. In Encryption complete document or content is encrypted, transmitted and decrypted back by receiver.  In below image, for encryption, the public key (the green key) is used to encrypt, the private key (the red key) to decrypt.
2. In digital signing, hash of content is signed (hash encrypted using private key) so that receiver can decrypt using public key and verify hash by recalculating hash of content.  (unlike encryption and decryption, Hash can't give back content, its one way process.)

This process makes sure that

a. Author is one who claims it and

b. Content or document has not changed since signing. (Changing a single char of content will change the hash!!)

[image: Encryption Vs Digital Signature]